# Filter Data Times

Tags: java, arrays, datetime, arraylist, collections

This block of code filters (discards) the latest (index 0) reference time that passes a test. The result of the filter allows the user to display the next latest reference time. I am trying to figure out how to filter out (discard) both the latest and the next latest reference time in the output.

```
// This routine filters out any DataTimes from a sequence that have a
// reference time later than "clock". If the flag "prevRun" is true then
// it also filters out any DataTimes with the latest reference time
// that passes the "clock" test. This allows the caller to see the
// previous run of some model. Returns the latest reference time remaining
// in the sequence. Caller allocates and own "times".
//
// -- implementation
// ---------------------------------------------------------
// Correct return of latest reference time dependent on default construction
// of AbsTime being a time_t of zero.
// "prevRun" feature is implemented by making a recursive call with "clock"
// set to the latest reference time in the sequence minus one.
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

private static Date filterByClock(List<DataTime> times, Date clock,
        boolean prevRun) {
    int next, check;
    long latest = 0L;
    long curRef;
    if (times == null || times.size() == 0 || clock == null) {
        return clock;
    }

    for (next = check = 0; check < times.size(); check++) {
        curRef = (times).get(check).getMatchRef();
        if (curRef > clock.getTime()) {
            continue;
        }
        if (latest < curRef) {
            latest = curRef;
        }
        if (next < check) {
            times.set(next, times.get(check));
        }
        next++;
    }

    if (next < check) {
        for (int i = next; i < check; i++) {
            times.remove(next);
        }
    }

    if (prevRun) {
        return filterByClock(times, new Date(latest - 1), false);           
    } else {
        return new Date(latest);
    }
}
```

Comment: You have not rigorously defined "latest", "next latest" and "filter out".  All of these can be interpreted ambiguously.  For example, "filter out" could be interpreted as "extract" (i.e. keep) or "discard".  This is one of the major issues in writing requirements in a natural language, you have to remain vigilant for ambiguities.

Comment: @JimGarrison  Thank you. I added some clarification to the question.

Comment: What is your problem is there any error, etc..

Comment: @janith1024, there is no error, I am just trying to figure what I need to do to discard the two latest data times instead of just the latest data time.

Comment: Would be helpful to see some examples: input data and the expected result. Ideally, along with actual result -- that'd clarify to people what's required there and solve a lot of unnecessary questions.

Comment: I think you want to return two Date objects from this method is that?